# PL/SQL: ORA-00936: missing expression while using trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I am trying to update a table in one database from another using a trigger. I am getting the missing expression error which i am not able to figure out the reason why. The error is at the line `:new.FO_CD != :old.FO_CD`. I am also getting **PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored** error at the line `:new.END_DT != :old.END_DT OR`. What might be causing these two errors?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_UPDATE_ITIN

AFTER DELETE OR UPDATE

ON FDL.PLA_ET 

REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD 

FOR EACH ROW 

BEGIN 

IF DELETING THEN

UPDATE

    FMS.ITIN

SET

    PLN_ET_UUID = NULL

WHERE

    PLN_ET_UUID = :OLD.PLN_ET_UUID;

ELSIF UPDATING THEN

    IF
      :new.START_DT != :old.START_DT OR

       :new.END_DT != :old.END_DT OR

       :new.CREATED_DTTM != :old.CREATED_DTTM OR

       :new.CREATED_USER_ID != :old.CREATED_USER_ID OR

       :new.ACT_UUID != :old.ACT_UUID OR

       :new.FO_CD != :old.FO_CD

    THEN UPDATE FMS.ITIN

        SET

            START_DATE = :new.START_DT,

            END_DATE = :new.END_DT,

            CREATION_DATE = = :new.CREATED_DTTM,

            CREATED_BY_USER = :new.CREATED_USER_ID,

            ACT_UUID = :new.ACT_UUID,

            FO_CTL_NBR = :new.FO_CD

        WHERE

            PLN_ET_UUID = :new.PLN_ET_UUID;

     END IF;

END IF;

END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
UPDATE fms.itin SET 
        start_date = :new.start_dt,
        end_date = :new.end_dt,
        creation_date = = :new.created_dttm,          --> here
        created_by_user = :new.created_user_id,
```

You've got two consecutive `= =` signs.

---

Maybe there are other errors, but without your tables, I can't run code you posted. Consider posting `CREATE TABLE` statement.